# Divide a c# class into it's parts

Tags: c#, reflection

if I have a Portable Class Library with a class

```
public class Class1
: EntityBaseClass
{
    public string Property1{get;set;}
    public string Property2{get;set;}
}
```

and a second class that contains an instance of class 1

```
public class Class2
: EntityBaseClass
{
    public string Property1{get;set;}

    public Class1 Property2{get;set;}
}
```

How can I devide class 2 so that I can get a dictionary in form of

```
Dictionary<Type, object>
```

where 'Type' is the type of Class1 and 'object' is the instance of class 1?

For persistence reasons I have to break a class into it's parts and have to save each instance separatly.

The plan is to implement a `Save<T>(T entity)` methode. This method picks out properties that derive from a special baseclass and save it into the datastore.

Because of the pcl library type there is no complete reflection subset of the .net Framework.

I tryed to do it with reflection and serialization without success but a lot of head aches. Attributes don't work too. Any hints how to start?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `List<EntityBaseClass>`instead of `Dictionary<Type, object>`

E.g)

```
List<EntityBaseClass> list = new List<EntityBaseClass>();
Class1 cl1 = new Class1();
list.Add(cl1);
Class2 cl2 = new Class2();
list.Add(cl2);
```

When you want to check type

```
foreach (EntityBaseClass item in list)
{
    if (item.GetType() == typeof(Class1))
    {
        Class1 cl1 = (Class1)item;
        //Your code
    }
    else
    {
        Class2 cl2 = (Class2)item;
        //Your code
    }
}
```

I hope it will help you.

Comment: If it would be so easy, but I have a class2 that CONTAINS an instance of class1. And I need both instance of class1 and instance of class2 in some kind of collection.